# How does $φ(n,x) = (2x)^n$ constitute a dynamical system?

Tags: dynamical-systems

I'm trying to make sense of the example in the following passage.

> Definition 1.1. On the topological space X, if there exists a map φ : T × X → X
> satisfying the following conditions, then (X, φ) is called a dynamical system: (where T
> is, for example, R, Z, N, etc.)
>
> (1) φ(x, 0) = x for any x ∈ X.
>
> (2) φ(t, φ(s, x)) = φ(s + t, x) for any x ∈ X, s, t ∈ T
>
> When T = R, t ∈ T is meant as continuous time. That is, φ(x, t) represents the location
> in X after a time t starting from the initial point x. On the other hand, T = Z or N is meant as a discrete time or number of trial iterations. For the example f(x) = 2x we saw at the beginning, if we consider φ(n, x) = f<sup>n</sup>(x), we can confirm that the definition of the dynamical system is satisfied.

I don't understand how this example constitutes a dynamical system; it doesn't seem to meet the first requirement, although it does meet the second.

If x is set to zero (n>0), I get...

φ(n, 0) = f<sup>n</sup>(0) = (2*0)<sup>n</sup> = 0<sup>n</sup> = 0 ≠ n.

If I suppose that the variables are in the wrong order and instead set n to zero (x≠0), I get...

φ(0, x) = f<sup>0</sup>(x) = (2x)<sup>0</sup> = 1 ≠ x.

Am I misunderstanding something? Am I screwing up basic calculations somehow and need to get a full night's sleep? Or is the text wrong?

Comment: Since $\varphi:T\times X \rightarrow X$, it should be $\varphi(0,x) = x$ for any $x\in X$.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @Arastas After some consultation, your answer is indeed the correct interpretation. If you write it below as an answer, I'll select it as best answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what $f^n(x)$ means, but it seems that it is not $\left(f(x)\right)^n$. Probably, it is the iterative application of the function $f$, e.g., $f^3(x)=f\left(f\left(f(x)\right)\right)$. Then it works for me since $f^0(x)=x$.
Anyway, the required $\phi$ should be $\phi(n,x) = 2^nx$ for $n \in N$.

Comment: Thanks, that was it!